# Why is Airflow UI not showing Dags?

Tags: python, docker, airflow

I was running Airflow using the official docker-compose file, which I removed to add custom credentials, using the command:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml down --volumes --rmi all
```

Now, after making the necessary changes my UI is not showing dags, In the Webserver, scheduler, worker container the dags directory has been mapped.

Even my containers are running in the healthy state.
My docker compose file looks like

```
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-abhigyan97/airflow}
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://**Custom_Postgres_User**:**Custom_Postgres_Pass**@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://**Custom_Postgres_User**:**Custom_Postgres_Pass**@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'False'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DEFAULT_TIMEZONE: 'IST'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
  volumes:
    - /home/ubuntu/apache-airflow/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - /home/ubuntu/apache-airflow/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - /home/ubuntu/apache-airflow/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-50000}"
  depends_on:
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: **Custom_Postgres_User**
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: **Custom_Postgres_password**
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "**Custom_Postgres_User**"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8050:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: version
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: '**Custom_User_Name**'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: '**Custom_Password**'

  flower:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery flower
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

Why is my dags not showing in the UI? How do I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show how your docker-compose file looks like?

Comment: @SreeramTP i have added the compose file.

Comment: ls /home/ubuntu/apache-airflow/dags shows the dag files?

Comment: Yes the dags are present there, and even in the container the volumes mapped have dags.
I even tried passing the environment variable of dags_folder to the compose file, but still no luck.

Is this happening because i deleted the volumes with compose down? as earlier it was working.

Comment: are you sure there are no import errors in the DAG? It should be shown in webserver if that is the case

Comment: Yes, There is nothing wrong with dag.
Today morning itself I ran everything, but since the time i edited my compose file to get custom credentials for db and webserver since that time, my webserver is not showing dags.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234971/discussion-between-abhi-and-sreeram-tp).